# Read a html form in c# windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have seen [this tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-14-Exercise-Whack-a-Bob-App)

Can I communicate the html code with c# code, for example, you make a form in html5 and the user must be put his name, some form of that name is received by c# code?

Comment: comunicate the html code with c# code? what?

Comment: pass parametrer ;for example when a button has been submit, i want that the app save the content in isolateStorage <input type=text name="person" id="person"/><button onclick="save"/> how i can do this ?

Comment: your question title is very confusing. It sounds like you're trying to read the contents of a remote web page. It's content however sounds like you are trying something different tho (maybe at least... hard to understand what you are trying to do in general)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use C# as a "backend" language you have to use XAML to "views". But you can use [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) control to render HTML documents in XAML pages.

Comment: I agree, use the webcontrol ;-)

Comment: Yes but for example when a button has been submit, i want that the app save the content in isolateStorage   <input type=text name="person" id="person"/><button onclick="save"/> how i can do this ?